# Android studio build error with manifest Dex

Tags: android, merge, dex

I have a problem after adding kigin activity. Now when I am trying to compile is says:

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex"

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<manifest package="com.google.android.gms.base" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
 <application>
  <activity android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"/>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It seems, somewhere app dependencies gets conflicted. Use `./gradlew :app:dependencies` to get tree dependencies of your project. Make sure one library doesn't include dependency that some other library is implicitly adding it.

Comment: I found this mainfest with 2 errors.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License